# Building time for Chrome V8 and Chromium

Tags: v8, chromium

I am interested in changing some codes in Chrome V8 and Chromium, but it seems that compilation is too long (like 4 hours for Chromium)

I hope to know is there any incremental build supported, and what is your building time for:  Chrome V8 (https://developers.google.com/v8/build) and Chromium (https://www.chromium.org/Home)?

I am using Windows, but I can switch to another OS if it is building faster

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes, it takes quite a while to compile v8 and Chromium.

The first thing you should do is run the build in parallel: `-j8` for a quad core machine for example. It can also build on multiple machines - see [the documentation](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-with-Gyp) for more flags.

Also, of course subsequent builds will be much faster and compilation artifacts will be reused. Subsequent compiles can be under a minute.

Comment: A minute? You are referring to V8 or chromium?

Comment: V8, in subsequent compilations.